# How to add type to a key in an object in typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have this type defined:

```
type PayloadTypes =
  | "VIEW_OFFER_DETAILS"
  | "ADD_TO_CART"
  | "MORE_INFO_ITEM"
  | "SHOW_ITEM_LOCATION";
```

I have an object which has a few keys but I don't want to define every key in the object, I just want the `payload` key to be defined

```
actions: [
  {
    type: "postback",
    text: "View details",
    payload: "VIEW_OFFER_DETAILS", // <- this one
    metadata: {
      userId,
      offer: JSON.stringify(offer)
    }
  }
]
```

How would you do in typescript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
type Action = { payload: PayloadTypes, [key: string]: any }
type ActionsList = Action[]
```

it's a very good way to incrementally type objects as you have a better understanding of their required structure. any named/defined params you type will have the indicated type, anything else will have `any`. Keep in mind this *doesn't* check against unknown object properties. So if `Action` can only have `type`, `text`, `payload`, and `meta`

```
action["somethingElse"] = 1
```

is perfectly valid given the above definition.